# Titan graph: Finding vertices without outgoing edges

Tags: graph, titan, gremlin

I have Parent vertex (P) connected to child vertices (C1, C2, C3,..Cn) (via an outgoing edge Label "dep") , Where Cn can be very huge. These child vertices (C1, C2,..) may or may not be connected to other vertices via an outgoing edge label "frnds". Is there a way in Gremlin to find out all Child vertices of (P) that does not have any out going edges with label "frnds" ?

Regards,
Kumar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The toy graph:

```
g = new TinkerGraph()
p = g.addVertex('p')
c1 = g.addVertex('c1')
c2 = g.addVertex('c2')
c3 = g.addVertex('c3')
o1 = g.addVertex('o1')
o2 = g.addVertex('o2')
g.addEdge(p, c1, 'dep')
g.addEdge(p, c2, 'dep')
g.addEdge(p, c3, 'dep')
g.addEdge(c1, o1, 'frnds')
g.addEdge(c1, o2, 'frnds')
g.addEdge(c2, o2, 'frnds')
```

A solution for your query description (probably not the smartest):

```
r = []; g.v('p').out('dep').store(r).outE('frnds').outV.sideEffect{r.remove(it)}
```

output:

```
r
==>v[c3]
```

Update:
Bit a shorter version, probably also bit more efficient:

```
g.v('p').out('dep').filter{!it.outE('frnds').hasNext()}
==>v[c3]
```

Comment: The edges "frnds" have certain property keys [like name, map-ratio (some decimal number between 0 to 1 indicating the closeness) ] and also the edges are sorted based on map-ratio value. So the first edge from c1 will always have the highest score. Is it possible to enhance this query "g.v('p').out('dep').filter{!it.outE('frnds').hasNext()}" further to return all child vertices having first edge (with highest map-ratio) within a particular range like betwen 0.5 to 0.7?

Answer (score 0):

g.v('p').out('dep').filter{!it.outE('frnds').hasNext()}.range(0,100) query works even faster when u sepcify range. It will get 100 vertices with no outgoing edges